# Listing All Days For 1 Year ( PHP )

Tags: php, date

I'm building a website which gives users the ability to add an event up to one year in the future and I want to show it in a simple drop down box like so:

```
<select>
<option value="2014-10-25">25th October 2014</option>
<option value="2014-10-26">26th October 2014</option>
<option value="2014-10-27">27th October 2014</option>
<option value="2014-10-28">28th October 2014</option>
<option value="2014-10-29">29th October 2014</option>
etc
etc
</select>
```

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: I just want to keep things simple

Comment: what is this? a dropdown from january 1 to december 31?, why not just a datepicker thats much simplier

Comment: But what's more simple than "<input id="datepicker" type="date"/>" ? But you'll have your reasons

Comment: @michael - Date isn't supported on Firefox or IE

Comment: @Ghost Lets forget datepickers, I'm only after a simple dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$day = date('Y-m-d');
$last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . '+ 1 year'));
while($day < $last_day) {
    echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.date('jS F Y', strtotime($day)).'</option>';
    $day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day . ' + 1 day'));
}
```

If you need to do that before 5.3.0 like previous answer required, not tested it but you get idea how to make, you can also cache strtotime into variable if you want to make it faster, or even just increase it by days length in seconds.